# How do I prevent table cells from shifting when hiding other cells in table?

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table, webforms, alignment

As simple as this sounds, I am modifying this tool that should display the vehicle Model for trucks, and hide them for Trailers, etc. I set the display to "none" and "Visible" to false in the code behind, and when I search for a trailer, the cells had moved to the right.

I tried using CSS floats, but nothing worked. I am using my company's template, so I would rather not make too many changes, if possible.

Here are code snippets:

**HTML/ASP**

```html
<tr>
    <td style="display: none;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDisplayModel" runat="server" CssClass="bold"
            CssStyle="display: none;" Visible="false" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblModel" runat="server" CssClass="NormalText" 
            CssStyle="display: none;" name="Model:" Visible="false" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="control_label">Service Date:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblServiceDate" runat="server" CssClass="NormalText" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="control_label">District:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFleetOwnerDistrict" runat="server" CssClass="NormalText" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

**C#/Code Behind**

```
if (equipment.equipment_type.Contains("TK"))
{
    lblModel.Visible = true;
    lblDisplayModel.Text = "Model:";
    lblDisplayModel.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    lblModel.Visible = false;
    lblDisplayModel.Visible = false;
}
```

[image]

Can someone please give me some hints?

Thank you.

Comment: Start by not using `style="display: none;"` in table row/cells. It will mess everything up.

Comment: Thank you! This helps, but now there is an empty row where the label was. If I remove the cell, the other cells will shift again.

Comment: What is wrong with an empty row? Or do you specify a default row height somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding, try changing the text. The cell (td) probably wants *something* in there as a kind of padding so add an html space.

I'm not sure which label to use so I'll make one up here.

```
// don't hide the label, just change the text, if possible.
lblMyLabel.Text = "&nbsp;";
```

Not positive it will work but might do it.